# How to extract multiple numbers from a string and assign to individual variables

Tags: ruby, regex, local-variables

Lets say I have the string `"first=53 second=65 third=82"`. How do I assign each value to variables `x`, `y`, `z`?

Edit: The words must match as well. With the + signs and exact number of spaces.

Comment: regexes need a pattern to look for. What is the pattern you're establishing here? first -> x, second -> y, third -> z?

Comment: @JonathanMee yes. I believe the regex is this:

/^first=\d+\ssecond=\d+\sthird=\d+/ But not sure how to extract

Comment: The edit made your question incomprehensible.

Answer (score 6):

```
str = "first=53 second=65 third=82"
x, y, z = str.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, not what I'm looking for. The words must match as well. With the + signs and exact number of spaces. I forgot to mention it in the question.

Comment: Can't think of any intelligent use for that. Anyway, if you already know where everything is in the string, just get it off the string index. `x, y, z = [str[6..7], str[16..17], str[25..26]].map(&:to_i)`